# Paypal SDK - Returning "Approved" when the Dashboard says "Completed" after payment execution

Tags: php, paypal, payment

I am using the following code to execute a payment that has been approved on Paypal.com by the user:

```
// Get the order object
$order_object = new Order($_GET["orderid"]);

 // Complete the payment
$payment = Payment::get($order_object->paypal_payment_id, $apiContext);

//Set the payer id
$order_object->SetPayerId($_GET["PayerID"]);

try
{
    // PaymentExecution object includes information necessary
    // to execute a PayPal account payment.
    // The payer_id is added to the request query parameters
    // when the user is redirected from paypal back to your site
    $execution = new PaymentExecution();
    $execution->setPayer_id($_GET["PayerID"]);

    //Execute the payment
    // (See bootstrap.php for more on `ApiContext`)
    $finished_payment = $payment->execute($execution, $apiContext); 
}
catch(PayPal\Exception\PPConnectionException $e)
{
    echo "<p>PPConnectionException - Already executed payment?</p>";
}

echo "Payment state: " . $finished_payment->getState() . '<br/>';
echo "Payment ID:" . $finished_payment->getId() . '<br/>';
```

If I get the state of the order before I execute it, it returns `created` which is fine, but then after execution using this code it comes back with the state `approved`.

This would be fine if `approved` meant that the transaction is completed, however on the developer dashboard the transaction shows as `completed` as I expected!

Why would the code be returning `approved` when it is really `completed`?

Thanks

**UPDATE: I've just checked http://sandbox.paypal.com and logged in as my merchant test account and the customer test account that I used and both also say that the transaction is completed.
I can prove this because if I try to re-execute the order, it returns a 500 error.
This is really confusing why it returns inconsistent data...**

Screenshots:

Returned from code above...

[image]

View of order on Developer website...
[image]

**Does `Approved` mean `Completed`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, approved mean completed, by the documentation in here: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#execute-an-approved-paypal-payment
The response must a "state": "approved", if everything goes well.

Answer (score 2):

The asker fails to distinguish between a Payment and a Sale.

"approved" is final happy state of a Payment. 
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#look-up-a-payment-resource

Once a Payment is approved, a Sale is created. You can then find it in the "transactions/related_resources" field of the Payment JSON.
"completed" is a happy state of a Sale.